# Programming Atmel ATMega 32-16pu using Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, avr, atmega

Some time ago, I bought the ATMega32-16PU and I thought, I could program it with Raspberry PI's GPIO pins. I tried it several times and I realized that ATMega32-16pu needs 5v and 5v could break my Raspberry PI so I bought schmitt trigger to shift the voltages of the signals that are going back to the PI.
Now I'm thinking, if it's even possible to program the ATMega with Raspberry.. If it isn't, what kind of programmer should I buy?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "5V could break my Raspberry Pi" especially given the fact that since Pi 2 (if I'm not mistaken) the board has not one but two 5V VDD pins which you can use for supplying some power to external things. This includes powering a controller in order to flash its memory. There are multiple tutorials on this topic including (but not only) from [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/program-an-avr-or-arduino-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins/overview). If the power is an issue (I don't see why) you can always power the controller from another (not the Pi) source.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Yeah, you can output 5V from RPi but if you try to input 5V, it can break the RPi...

Comment: You can do that but you need some very small extra work (put a resistor like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22841) or a level converter). Otherwise using UART would have been impossible yet the Pi has it. The USB port also goes with 5V.

Answer (score 1):

AVRs usually also work on 3.3V with maybe reduced max allowed clock frequencies (the older ones can go down to 2.7V, the newer ones even to 1.8V), so you directly can use your Raspis SPI to program them - without any level shifters.

You also may use newer AVRs (e.g. the mostly compatible AtMega324 - you also can easily scale up or down on flash/memory size). So you can set the fuse to `ckdiv8` so it is active while programming (being 3.3V capable at this time) and remove the clock divider at startup in your program, if you require the maximum clock frequency.

If you are tied to the old Mega16 then at least you need no level shifter for the inputs, since the AVRs threshold for 'high' is 0.6*VCC. Except for the Reset Pin, but chances are good that this works anyway. So only the MISO Pin does need some care. A Simple voltage divider should be enough   `AVR) --[ 10k ]-- (RPI) --[ 20k ]-- (GND`

It also seems that you can use `avrdude` with the programmer `linuxspi`. Please refer documentation.

This [Article](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Raspberry_Pi_als_Universalprogrammer#Einstellungen_avrdude_.C3.BCberpr.C3.BCfen_und_testen) of a german micro controller community website advises the adaption of the config files to set the correct pin that is used to reset the AVR and suggests the adaption of the baud rate in the config file.

```
programmer 
  id       = "linuxspi";
  desc     = "Use Linux SPI device in /dev/spidev*";
  type     = "linuxspi";
  reset    = 25; # <- your reset pin
  baudrate = 100000;
;
```

The avrdude command line to read the flash content to `/dev/null` for a connection test then looks somehow like:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/avrdude -c linuxspi -p m32p -P /dev/spidev0.0 -U flash:r:"/dev/null":r
```

Comment: You can't program ATMega32-16PU with 3.3V because it runs on 16MHz and needs min 5V

Comment: @Miksu I now mentioned the reduced frequency on lower voltages

Comment: Really? I think I tried it already and it didn't work.. Well I have to try again

Comment: @Miksu then maybe the Reset pin is not read as high on 3.3V. May be you have to use an transitor to controll it with you raspberry. Another reason may be that your AVR is still runnung on 1MHz (had you set the fuses properly?) and your ISP-Speed is to high. reduce it to 100kHz by making the above adaptions.

Comment: Fuses? I don't even know what they are or how to set them

Comment: @Miksu if you have not done this - then your AVR is running at 1Mhz on the internal Oszillator - ignoring your external crystals. And since AVR-Dude runs by default the ISP at 400kHz the AVR is too slow.
Please refer the datasheet chapter about the clock system and the chapter about memory programming.

Comment: @Miksu another hint: the fuses setting are a bit confusing, because they are inverted and are rather complex. Search for a tool Burn-O-Mat. that is a java-based gui for avrdude. some AVRs are pretty good integrated, so you can select the correct settings in a Window and see the values you have to program to the 3 fuse bytes (or directly write it from the tool)